# PHPWord Addpage method misses

Tags: php, phpword

I am trying to work with PHPWord. But when I try to insert this code-line

```
$document->AddPage();
```

I get the following  error...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPWord_Template::AddPage() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Anderen\PHPWord\Testtemplate.php on line 37
```

When I search in the included `PHPWord.php` file, I can't find the method Addpage so I do not wonder it doesn't work. But my question is, how can I solve this problem? I already use the latest version...

Thanks,
olivier

Comment: Who is telling you to use that method in the first place? Can you post a link=?

Comment: I  tried it on my localhost (XAMPP)...

Comment: No, who is giving you the idea that a method named `AddPage` should exist?

Comment: Hi, I fount that on de forum of PHPWord... Here => http://phpword.codeplex.com/workitem/51 (this is also the code I want to implement)...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the addPageBreak() method of the Section object

**EDIT**

```
require_once 'PHPWord.php'; 
$PHPWord = new PHPWord(); 
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

$tenant_arr = array("Mark","Baker"); 
$j = 0; 
foreach($tenant_arr as $value) {
    $section->addText($value);
    $section->addPageBreak();
}
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'RTF');
$objWriter->save('myWordFile.rtf');
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that also and I get the same result:
"Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPWord_Template::addPageBreak() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Anderen\PHPWord\Testtemplate.php on line 41"

And my code is:
require_once 'PHPWord.php';
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('Template.docx');
$tenant_arr = array("Olivier");
$j = 0;
foreach( $tenant_arr as $value)
{
if($j > 0){$document->AddPage();}
$document->setValue('Value1', 'Sun');
$document->addPageBreak();
$j++;
} 
$document->save('Solarsystem.docx');

Comment: A PHPWord_Template object is not a PHPExcel_Section object.... page breaks are within sections, and a PHPWord document comprises one or more sections; but you should be editing the PHPWord object, not the template object

Comment: Hello Mark, I not understand what you mean, can you explain it again for me?